# Bilinear form and double cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a double cover of curves (smooth and projective), and $E$ a vector bundle on $X$ with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $\phi:E\otimes E\rightarrow \mathcal O_X$. With this given, I can associate to it a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $$\pi_*\phi:\pi_*E\otimes\pi_*E\rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal O_X$$

My question is , how could one construct $\phi$ starting from $\pi_*\phi$? I mean if given $\psi:\pi_*E\otimes\pi_*E\rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal O_X$, could one construct a $\phi$ s.t $$\pi_*\phi=\psi$$

Comment: If $\psi$ is of the form $\pi_*\phi$, then $\psi$ is $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$-bilinear, not merely $\mathcal{O}_Y$-bilinear.

Comment: So I think in general it is not true that any $\psi$ is of the form $\pi_*\phi$?

Comment: That is correct.  There is a necessary and sufficient condition for existence of $\phi$: $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$-bilinearity of $\psi$.

Comment: @JasonStarr, could you please detail a little bit your ansewer, I didn't see why this is sufficient condition!

Comment: Please read Exercise II.5.17(e) on p. 128 of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry".